# How to access the second element that has the same class name in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a 2 elements on my web page that has the same class name and I am trying to access the second element and I am unable to do that. I tried [position=1] and by putting [1] at the end of my xpath expression

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tableType value']")
```

the above returns the following 2 elements

I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tableType value']")[1]
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tableType value'][position=1]")
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: By.xpath() was just what I needed (I copied the correct value in Firefox by doing a right click on the element and selecting "Inspect"). With the JavaScript / Node.js version of Selenium WebDriver, it looks like we cannot do By.css("TagName")[1] to select the second tag name with the value searched.

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='tableType value'])[2]")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='tableType value'])[position()=2]")
```

XPath starts counting at 1, so the second element is at `position()` 2

Comment: I tried both of them, but still returns both the elements.

Comment: Ok. You probably have many nested divs in different contexts. You might need to use additional predicates to better filter your result. Show your code (link to it, and add the relevant parts here). I added parentheses above, which will select only *one* element, the second in the whole document, but that might not be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Hi please find the below code to click on the second element having the same class names.
[1] means if you would like to click on second, [2] means if you would like to click on third....

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('classname')[1].click()`

Answer (score -1):

You have to use:

> driver.find_**elements**(by, value)

or

> driver.find_**elements**_by_class_name(name)

For example:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'something')
elements[0].click()
elements[1].click()
```