# How to access the second element that has the same class name in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When trying to automate our application, there are two buttons with same name.

I'm not able to find a way to recognize these. Please let me know what could be the other ways to identify these elements in selenium webdriver in java

Comment: Please post HTML source of those two buttons

Comment: HTML snippet is needed. At first take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23819540/2504101

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use xpath indexing option.

```
By.xpath("(//input[@name='Button'])[2]")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can go with xpath always if there is no uniqueness with attribute. For e.g. if you want to find an element which has text `foo` and name `button` then I'll prefer xpath as below if name is not unique there:

```
//*[@name='button' and text()='foo']
```

Or For different class but same name

```
//button[@name='button' and @class='xyz']
```

or For different text but same name

```
//input[@name='button' and contains(text(),'Click Here')]
```

or for different tags but same name

```
//button[@name='button']
//input[@name='button']
```

Just go with any unique property and make a customized xpath.

I hope you can also use java script for this as well for e.g.

```
WebElement butttonToClick = driver.findElement(By.name("button"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[1].click();",butttonToClick );
```

Where `arguments[1]` means second element which has same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with xpath methods like following-sibling/preceding siblings.

For example if the Button is located to any unique webelement try to identify that webelement first and by using different xpath methods like following-siblings, content, preceding siblings you can access the web element.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating loop on button with same name and same class

```
List<WebElement> listofItems= 
driver.findElements(By.className("actions")); 
System.out.println(listofItems);
System.out.println(listofItems.size());
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
for (int s=1; s<=listofItems.size(); s++)
{ 
 /*Getting the list of items again so that when the page is
   navigated back to, then the list of items will be refreshed
   again */ 
   listofItems= driver.findElements(By.className("actions")); 
       
   //Waiting for the element to be visible
   //Used (s-1) because the list's item start with 0th index, like in 
     an array
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(listofItems.get(s-1)));

  //Clicking on the first element 
    listofItems.get(s-1).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.print(s + " element clicked\t--");
    System.out.println("pass");
    driver.navigate().back();
        
    }
```