# SELENIUM FIND ELEMENT BY XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have three elements with the *same button class* and *span class names*. I wanted to use xpath to select the second span class but I always get it wrong.

I used:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/section[2]/div[2]/form/div[9]/button/span[1]").click()
```

But I get error. I also tried the following but get the same error message.

```
result = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='_1h5on2Eq5J']")[2].click()

browser.switch_to.frame(result)

results = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/section[2]/div[2]/form/div[9]/button/span[1]")
```

Below is an excerpt of the html. My interest is to find the second element.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the second element that has the same class name in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819397/how-to-access-the-second-element-that-has-the-same-class-name-in-selenium)

Comment: Use your browser's Inspect Element feature to get the exact xpath of that element.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @JohnGordon: In my experience, this doesn't always work.  Some of these paths are ridiculously long, incredibly specific, and often return nothing when you try to use them.  So you still have to be smart with your xpath.

Comment: @stdunbar. I tried your solution earlier but did not work

Answer (score 2):

You can use xpath to find text that contains a substring.

Here's the selector you would want for the "Expand" button:

```py
"//button//span[contains(., 'Expand')]"
```